Why we needed to prove that $f$ is the zero map before using the lifting criteria?
Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution and the hint given:
Show that if a path-connected, locally path-connected space $X$ has $\pi_1(X)$ finite, then every map $X \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic.[Use the covering space $\mathbb R \to S^1.$]
My questions are:
1- Why we needed to prove that $f_*$ is the zero map before using the lifting criteria?
2- Why we needed to use the covering space $\mathbb R \to S^1$ specifically? And how will this lead us to that $f$ homotopic to the constant map specifically?
Could anyone explain these questions to me please?
Lifting Criteria:
Suppose given a covering space $p: (\tilde{X} , \tilde{x_0}) \to ( X, x_0)$ and a map $f: (Y, y_0) \to (X, x_0)$ with $Y$ path-connected and locally path-connected. Then a lift $\tilde{f}: (Y, y_0) \to (\tilde{X} , \tilde{x_0}) $ of $f$ exists iff $f_*(\pi_1(Y, y_0)) \subset p_*(\pi_1 (\tilde{X} , \tilde{x_0})).$
I do not know what exactly in the definition requires $f_*$ to be zero. Could someone clarify this to me?

Presumably by $f$ you mean the induced map on $\pi_1$. Can you [edit] the question to add the lifting criterion (for covering maps), as you understand it? If you do not understand the lifting criterion then that's what you should venture on before trying to solve this exercise.

@ronno I just did, thanks for pointing this out!

By the lifting criterion, $f$ lifts to $\mathbb{R}$ iff $f_*(\pi_1(X, x_0)) \subseteq p_*(\pi_1(\mathbb{R}, 0)) = 0$ where $p\colon \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is the universal covering, whence $f_*$ must be trivial. Now $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, so there is a nullhomotopy $h_t\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ of the lift $\tilde{f}$ which yields a nullhomotopy $p \circ h_t\colon X \to S^1$ of $f$.

So $p_*$ is zero because it is the image of $\pi_1(\mathbb R)$ at the basepoint zero(I do not know why we choose this point specifically) which is trivial because $\mathbb R$ is contractible, right?

@Emptymind Yes. There's nothing special about the basepoint here, really, but 0 is the convention (sort of).
